# Grunt angularJs project without dependencies from backend's data

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, web-applications, gruntjs

I create my app with generator-angular.

Sometimes I should add some feature to my app before backend has been created. I use $httpBackend for mock data and here is simple code with I use:

**e2e-mocks.js**

```
angular.module('e2e-mocks', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .run(function ($httpBackend, OffersMock, RewardsMock) {
    // Mock list of offers
    $httpBackend.whenGET('api/offers').respond(OffersMock.get());
    // Mock list of rewards
    $httpBackend.whenGET('api/rewards').respond(RewardsMock.get());

    // For everything else, don't mock
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
  });

angular.module('app').requires.push('e2e-mocks');
```

As you can see if I add this script to web page, I no longer need to use backend server for getting data. I'm getting data from OffersMock service. I also use this service in my tests.

The problem is with path. 
Here is my file structure:

```
    .
    |____app
    | |____index.html
    | |____scripts
    | | |____app.js
    | | |____controllers
    | | | |____main.js
    | | | |____OffersCtrl.js
    | | |____services
    | | | |____OffersService.js
    | |____styles
    | | |____main.scss
    | |____views
    | | |____offers.html
    | | |____rewards.html
    |____karma.conf.js
    |____test
    | |____backend
    | | |____e2e-mocks.js
    | |____mock
    | | |____OffersMock.js
    | | |____RewardsMock.js
    | |____spec
    | | |____controllers
    | | | |____OffersController.js
    | | |____services
    | | | |____OffersService.js
```

I can't add to index.html my **e2e-mocks.js** file because app folder is a root of my web app. If move test folder to app folder all my test will be able to view in production server.

The question:
How I can add some mock scripts to my app while I'm developing and deploy easily without deleting test code from builded app manually?

Do you have any idea how to do this? Maybe you know some pattern for it or your personal best practice? Any advice will be useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a specific naming pattern for your local mocks, you could exclude those files during the build using Grunt's [globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#globbing-patterns).

For example, if you had a `grunt-contrib-concat` configuration like this:

```
//from the sample gruntfile    
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
    src: ['src/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
  }
}
```

...you could change it to this to exclude any files you created with a name pattern of `*-mymocks.js`:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
    src: ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*-mymocks.js'],
    dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
  }
}
```

The (minimal) downside is that you need to do this with each Yeoman task that might mistakenly move your local development mocks to your deployment destination.